# Methods in python

Tags: python, nltk

So I was going though [nltk](http://nltk.org/) and saw this code

```
entities = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
```

Now my question is that how do you people know which method to use when and what is the order of method calls?

Another strange code I saw was

```
nltk.corpus.words.words('en')
```

Now how would one interpret `.words` followed by `.words?` Why did we call words method twice here & how do I know when I need to call a method twice?

I just finished "Udacity - Intro. to CS (with Python)" but this "nltk" is getting way too confusing. Please help, have been struggling to get the logic of all these since couple of days.

Comment: `how do you people know which method to use when?` we check the documentation, try to understand the types involved, write some code and fail a few times. Then we eventually learn how to use a lib.

Comment: `nltk.corpus.words.words('en')` sounds like poor naming on someone's part. The first `words` isn't a method call - note the parentheses after the second on and not the first. It might be a variable or module.

Comment: It's not poor naming. It's very poor naming.

Comment: nltk.corpus.words.words('en') taken from section 3.4 of http://nltk.org/book/ch03.html

Answer (score 8):

You are not calling `words` twice. You are calling the `words` method of `words` module. It's all about namespaces and modules. Read more about Python [modules](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html).

:)

Comment: Followed that chapter. So according to section 6.4 its nltk/corpus/words/words.py being called/accessed as nltk.corpus.words.words , am I right ? So I have to be aware of this directory structure and modules in each subdirectory/directory & their function in order to access them ?

Comment: No. Module nltk/corpus/words has defined (poorly) a method called "words". You can play with namespaces like this: import nltk.corpus.words as words_module and after that, just simple call "words" method with words_module.words(...)

Comment: This is what I tried : - 1.] import nltk.corpus as nc ("WORKS"), 2.]
import nltk.corpus.words.words as ncw ( "ImportError: No module named words.words") , 3.] import nltk.corpus.words as ncw ("ImportError: No module named words")   Why these different behaviors ?

Comment: So this is what I found out: "nltk.corpus.words" is an object from "WordListCorpusReader" class. That is the reason you cannot import it. That class is defined in nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist, and you can see the code here -> http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordlist.html. So with the whole dotted notation, you are accessing to "words" method definded inside WordListCorpusReader class, referenced by "words" object defined inside "nltk.corpus" package.

Comment: You can get all he info typing:
>>> dir(nltk.corpus) # Extensive package info
>>> nltk.corpus.words.__class__ 
#<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist.WordListCorpusReader'
>>>> nltk.corpus.WordListCorpusReader.__class__
<type 'type'>

Comment: Im sorry but Alberto, how do you know all this stuff. i mean , suppose if it were some other "xyz" package instead of NLTK,so how would I know xyz.foo.bar.blah ?  I was able to code considerably good at the "CS101 Udacity.com" python class, but moving to nltk has stagnated it.Though I understand their code and all, but without understanding these basic things I cant move on. Consider this--"If I tld you to use "NLTK" package. So you'll import it first of all. Now how would you know what to append where i.e. nltk.foo.bar.blah OR nltk.zee.dee.dee etc ? How do u people go about it? Pls help

Comment: Just look into the NLTK docs (page I gave you a pair of comments before) and use Python's dir command to see what a module/object has to play with it. As Python docs says: dir -> "With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object". Anyway, look always at packages docs to find out what to use, and hoy to use them

Answer (score 3):

The `.` character in Python is not only for accessing methods. It denotes attribute access in some object. What exactly that means may depend on what the object is.

In your examples, `nltk.chunk` and `nltk.corpus.words` are both names of modules. `nltk` is a `package` which is a special kind of module that can contain other modules. So is `nltk.corpus`. (And actually, `nltk.chunk` is also a package, but you're using it as a regular module, rather than accessing another module within it.)

In `nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)`, the dots access the `chunk` attribute in the `nltk` module, then the `ne_chunk` attribute within the `nltk.chunk` module. That happens to be a function, which gets called.

In `nltk.corpus.words.words('en')`, the third dot looks up the `words` attribute within the `nltk.corpus.words` module.

Comment: Technically, `.` is used *only* for attribute access.  A method is simply a callable attribute.

Comment: Cud u help me understnd stepwise 1.]import nltk 2.]from nltk.corpus import words 3.]nltk.corpus.words <WordListCorpusReader in '.../corpora/words' (not loaded yet)>
 4.]nltk.corpus.words.words
 <bound method WordListCorpusReader.words of <WordListCorpusReader in '~/nltk_data/corpora/words'>>    Question is,how do I even know when to use nltk.corpus.words & when use nlt.corpus.words.words? Shall I memorize it? Do coders memorize such stuff? If no then,how do u people know (& from where) about these arrangements,that whether it should be x.foo.bar.blah OR x.blah.foo.hush? Pls,Im totally confused

Comment: @vinita: I think you're being thrown off by the fact that `nltk.corpus.words.words` has `words` twice. That's a design decision by the library designers (and as a bunch of other commenters have said, it may be a bad design). There are no rules about how deep a given thing will be, it depends on the design of the modules and packages in question. As for needing to memorize locations, I think that's optional. If you don't remember a function's exact location, you can always check the docs for a refresher. You'll probably learn the locations of things you use often, just by repeated use.

Comment: Hmm thanks,BTW I found that this http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/PythonModules/modules.html addresses my question. Heres a line from the link "But what if no one had told us about turtle? How would we know that it exists. How would we know what it can do for us?". It addresses my questions and confusion.